# How to make TableViewer exapandable in SWT?

Tags: java, tree, swt, jface, tableviewer

I made

```
class ViewContentProvider implements IStructuredContentProvider
```

which provides hierarchical data, also I made appropriate

```
class ViewLabelProvider extends LabelProvider implements ITableLabelProvider
```

Then I wrote

```
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
        viewer = new TableViewer(parent, SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL
                | SWT.V_SCROLL);
        viewer.setContentProvider(new ViewContentProvider());
        viewer.setLabelProvider(new ViewLabelProvider());
        // Provide the input to the ContentProvider

        viewer.setInput(...
```

Unfortunately, view displays only the members of topmost node. It does not display topmost node itself. Also, the more nested childs are not displayed, i.e. all displayed nodes displayed as childless.

Why? How to make `TableView` look like is is drawn everywhere as table with expandable nodes?

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't use a `TreeViewer`?

Comment: I have a question about `TreeViewer` too: how to make it to have columns?

Comment: Just use http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/nftopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/TreeViewerColumn.html

Comment: So, it is impossible to use `TableView` here?

Comment: @SuzanCioc If you want to respect a hierarchy, use `TreeViewer`. If you want to have columns, add `TreeColumn`s.

Comment: Then why `TableViewer` accepts `IStructuredContentProvider` which supports hierarchical structure? And why `TreeViewer` does not support it then?

Comment: @SuzanCioc Just use a `ITreeContentProvider` instead for the `TreeViewer`. [This](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJFace/article.html#jfaceviewers_types) is worth reading.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display nodes with parent-child relationship, then you should be using `org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer`.

If the information for the node has to be displayed with multiple columns like a table, then you can use the `org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewerColumn`.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps,

```
    Composite composite = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
    composite.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

    Group grp = new Group(composite, SWT.NONE);
    grp.setText(Messages.get().getValue("Some_text"));
    grp.setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.HORIZONTAL));

    tree = new Tree(grp, SWT.BORDER);
    tree.setLinesVisible(true);

    TreeColumn trclmnNewColumn = new TreeColumn(tree, SWT.NONE);
    trclmnNewColumn.setWidth(100);
    trclmnNewColumn.setText(Messages.get().getValue("Type"));

    TreeColumn trclmnNewColumn_1 = new TreeColumn(tree, SWT.CENTER);
    trclmnNewColumn_1.setWidth(60);
    trclmnNewColumn_1.setText(Messages.get().getValue("Value"));

    TreeItem treeItem = new TreeItem(tree, SWT.NONE);
    treeItem.setText("Some Value");

    TreeItem trtm1 = new TreeItem(treeItem, SWT.NONE);
    trtm1.setText("Some Value");

    TreeItem trtm2 = new TreeItem(treeItem, SWT.NONE);
    trtm2.setText("Some Value");

    treeItem.setExpanded(true);
```